# Howto combine unit testing with assert()

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, assert

Suppose that the preconditions of my object's functions are checked with `assert()`. How can I then, without ripping my hair off in the process, write meaningful unit tests that catches the precondition failures when I pass invalid parameters to the functions?

I mean, `assert()` will `abort()`, so how can I then perform all other tests after that?

Comment: @6equj5 - it's a good answer, thanks for adding it. However, since I asked the question 12 years ago, I've become much better at writing code AND tests so this is no longer an issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `assert()` with a macro that calls your unit-testing framework when unit-testing but evaluates to `assert()` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

As time passes, I've become less and less keen on using assert. But if you want to use it, I suggest writing your own version which throws exceptions (which can be caught), rather than calling abort().

Answer (score 3):

Run your tests in a sub-process.  Passing invalid parameters will cause the child to abort, but your test (the parent) continues running.